# Edit WP html code, but cannot find the page

Tags: php, html, wordpress, wordpress-theming

I am new to Word Press and I have been assigned to change something at work in our homepage.
I am always worked with raw HTML/CSS/php files, so I am a bit out of place here.

The page in question is the following: [GAN Integrity Solutions Products](http://www.ganintegrity.com/index.php/product-and-services/)

Inspecting the html I found where the CSS is (in the theme folder).

If I go in word press under pages, and I choose Products (which is the page I want) there is not content in it even in the text or visual editor. (but the page does indeed have content)

I installed the plugin called "Always edit in HTML" but it only removes the Visual tab and does not really replace it with the HTML tab (like I have seen a friend of mine has).

Also I am currently using WP v. 3.7.1 and I have not update because I still had to learn what happens when one updates (does it screw up my site? I can't afford to screw it up).

Anyone have any idea of what I am doing wrong or how I can solve this?

Btw the different "products" are created individually under "Portfolio" but what I would like to edit is that first link page html. What I need to do is instead of having pictures in the "squares" and then text as ones mouse over them, the reverse.

I would appreciate it!

Answer (score -1):

Can you try to login in Wordpress?
You should go to pages and search for the product page.
Then check the template part.
Go to your themes map again and search for that template.
Your code should be there.

This is my first comment. Hope it is helpfull.

Comment: In the products page under "template" in the right side bar, it says "portfolio" however in the theme page, where I can see the themes installed and the one in use is not the place where "portfolio" is. could you be more precise? Do you want me to look into portfolio or into my current theme?

Comment: Comments and Answers are different things, Drogon, check [answer].